# Parse file for recursive pattern

Tags: bash, sed, pipe

in my dir there are several files with the pattern

```
simulation_y_t
```

for all files with this pattern I would need to check whether in the last line of the file the word `hgip` comesup or not ...the word might not be separated by spaces from the surrounding characters but if it comes up it will come up within the last 20 characters of the line...

how would i be able to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using **`sed`**:

```
for file in *simulation_y_t*; do sed -n '$ s/.*hgip.\{0,16\}$/&/p' "$file"; done
```

It will check the last line of each file and if `hgip` comes within the last 20 characters it will print the line.

Here is the expanded version (printing the file names also):

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in *simulation_y_t*; do
    line="$(sed -n '$ s/.*hgip.\{0,16\}$/&/p' "$file")"
    [[ -n $line ]] && echo "$file: " "$line"
done
```

- The starting `$` (before the `s///` pattern) indicates the last line of the file.
- The pattern `hgip.\{0,16\}$` ensures that `hgip` occurs only with the last 20 characters of the line
- `line` will contain the line with match
- `[[ -n $line ]]` tests if the length of `$line` is non-zero, if so then the file and the matched last line will be printed.

---

This can also be done using **`grep`** with help from `tail`:

```
grep 'hgip.\{0,16\}$' < <(for f in *simulation_y_t*;do tail -1 "$f";done)
```

Here the logic is same as `sed`'s, in addition `tail -1` will give us the last lines of the files so that we can run `grep` over them.

**EDIT :**

If you want to delete the last line if it matches the conditions, use this:

```bsh
!/bin/bash
for file in *simulation_y_t*; do
   [[ -n "$(sed -n '$ s/.*hgip.\{0,16\}$/&/p' "$file")" ]] && sed -i.bak '$d' "$file"
done
```

The original file will be kept with a `.bak` extension, if you don't want that just use `-i` instead of `-i.bak`.

Comment: is it possible to incorporate that it deleted the last line if it comes up within this range?

Comment: @user3069326 so you wanna delete the last line if matched rather than printing?

Comment: yes...that is the thing

Comment: @user3069326 check my edits

Comment: is it possible just to overwrite the orignal fiel with the fiel which ecxlusdes the last lien in the cases...?

Comment: @user3069326 The script in the `EDIT :` section will do exactly that..if you don't want to back up use `sed -i` instead of `sed -i.bak` (it has also been mentioned in the answer)..